# return NULL value

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, icc, unique-ptr

#### Snippets of framebufferd3d11.h

```
namespace dx11 {
...
class FramebufferManager : public FramebufferManagerBase
{
public:
   ...
private:
   ...
   static struct Efb
   {
      ...
      std::unique_ptr<D3DTexture2D> resolved_color_tex;
      std::unique_ptr<D3DTexture2D> resolved_depth_tex;
   } m_efb;
};
} //namespace
```

#### Snippets of framebufferd3d11.cpp

```
namespace DX11
{
...
FramebufferManager::Efb FramebufferManager::m_efb;
...
FramebufferManager::FramebufferManager()
{
   ...
   m_efb.resolved_color_tex = NULL;
   m_efb.resolved_depth_tex = NULL;
}
} //namespace
```

---

If I compile with icc, I get a problem with NULL assign value, as NULL is defined as 0. How do I solve a problem like this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Compiler error? If so, what compiler error? Or unexpected behaviour? What did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: the problem is ICC doesn't know how to convert 0 to unique_ptr<D3DTexture2D> type... vc++ has it compiled without problem. i expect the unique_ptr<D3DTexture2D> to be null in some situation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, I think. Please delete the C tag.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct.  All of the following should work:

```
m_efb.resolved_color_tex = 0;
m_efb.resolved_color_tex = NULL;
m_efb.resolved_color_tex = nullptr;
```

A null pointer constant (like `0` or `NULL`) is implicitly convertible to `nullptr_t` and `unique_ptr` has an assignment operator that takes a `nullptr_t`.  If the version of ICC that you are using does not yet support `nullptr`, that could explain why the assignment of `NULL` doesn't work for you.

You may have better luck using `reset()`:

```
m_efb.resolved_color_tex.reset(NULL);
```

or, since `NULL` is the default argument:

```
m_efb.resolved_color_tex.reset();
```

Comment: how do i return a NULL value within std::unique_ptr<D3DTexture2D>?

Comment: no, it doesn't support nullptr in icc. i always defined nullptr as 0 to get it thru.

Comment: @lannyboy:  A default-constructed `std::unique_ptr`, a `std::unique_ptr` constructed explicitly with `0` (or `NULL`, or `nullptr`) as the constructor argument, or a `std::unique_ptr` that has been `.reset()`, `.reset(0)`, or `.reset(nullptr)` will all be null.

Comment: I changed my mind.  The code as written is correct, Visual C++ is correct to accept it, and Intel C++ Compiler is wrong not to accept it.

Comment: it is always having wierd result to have it compile at ICC. but it provides extra performance with cpu instruction sets.

Answer (score 1):

Never initialize members in the body of the constructor. If they have non-trivial constructor, it is first called and than `operator=` is used to reinitialize them. Instead use the base and member initializer list. Like:

```
FramebufferManager::FramebufferManager() :
   resolved_color_tex(NULL), resolved_depth_tex(NULL)
{
   ...
}
```

In your case it turns out that:

1. The default constructor (called if you mention either `resolved_color_tex()` or not mention it at all) already does what you want.
2. For primitive types, if you explicitly mention them, they will be zero-initialized. So any pointer members, no matter what type, if explicitly mentioned in the initializer list, will be NULL and you don't have to think about it any more.